Send velocity command using external node
I am looking to set the velocity of my robot's motors to zero based on a node external to ROS2 control. I have a separate node that will notify when to set the motors to zero and I am unsure how to plug this into the ROS2 control environment. Is there a way to do this without creating another process outside of ROS2 control?

Please clarify your question to help understand your system better. It's not clear how many nodes your already have. And also please explain what you've tried to do and what's not working or you would like to optimize about it.
